# Powershell, Loop through CSV and use Switch

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I'm setting up a script to automate some work and am having some trouble. I've tried some suggestions found online with no luck.

My goal is to loop through a CSV file, at each row, checking a specific cell for it's content, and then running a command based on that value with all the data in that row.

Here's what I have right now. It doesn't work, and I'm honestly not sure if I even have the syntax correct for stepping through each row, or if the switch is even setup to read the heading "Description" and compare it with the cases below.

```
Import-Csv $path | Foreach-Object {

foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties){
    switch ($property.description) {
        2019 {
            do something
        }
        2020 {
            do something
        }
        2021 {
            do something
        }
        2022 {
            do something
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sample of CSV

```
firstname,lastname,name,samaccountname,password,email,description,CAMPUS_ID
1test,1senior,1test 1senior,01testsenior,test1234,01testsenior@website.com,2019,1
1test,1junior,1test 1junior,01testjunior,test1234,01testjunior@website.com,2020,1
1test,1sophomore,1test 1sophomore,01testsophomore,test1234,01testsophomore@website.com,2021,1
1test,1freshman,1test 1freshman,01testfreshman,test1234,01testfreshman@website.com,2022,1
```

Comment: can you provide some of  your CSV?

Comment: if you add to your initial question it'll probably format correctly

Comment: Updated the original post with the CSV sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping! I ended up combining both what I posted, and Mathias fixed, and what Vivek posted. With some additional modification to store the row into variables, because they don't pass to switches.

```
Import-Csv 'PATH' | Foreach-Object {

$FirstName = $_.firstname
$LastName = $_.lastname
$Email = $_.email
$Password = $_.password
$Description = $_.description
$Campus = $_.CAMPUS_ID

    switch ($_.description) {
        '2019' {Do something with variables}
        '2020' {Do something with variables}
        '2021' {Do something with variables}
        '2022' {Do something with variables}
        default {echo "Default"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$obj = Import-Csv $path
switch($obj.PSObject.Properties.Value.Description)
{
    '2019' {'do 2019 thing'}
    '2020' {'do 2020 thing'}
    '2021' {'do 2021 thing'}
    '2021' {'do 2022 thing'}
    default {'do default thing'}
}
```

Comment: I tested this, it seems to work. However, I can't get it to work with the command I'm using. Does it make sense to reference the data of the row like this "$obj.PSObject.Properties.Value.email" ?  That would reference the "email" column, of the row that is currently in use?

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is unnecessary, just reference the `description` property of the current item in the pipeline (`$_`):

```
Import-Csv $path | Foreach-Object {
    switch ($_.description) {
        2019 {
            do something
        }
        2020 {
            do something
        }
        2021 {
            do something
        }
        2022 {
            do something
        }
    }
}
```